# Fuse ESB - ODE installation

Tags: jbossfuse, apache-servicemix, fuseesb

In the FUSE ESB, I tried to install the ODE feature using the command (install ode), but got an error as below.  Any help is appreciated

```
FuseESB:karaf@root> features:install ode
Error executing command: No feature named 'ode' with version '0.0.0' available
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apache ODE is not supported by Fuse ESB any longer. Apache ODE does not work with OSGi and its a project that is not active maintained and we do not recommend using it, as well JBI is also dead.

And the command is correct it says there is no feature named ode.

You can do a features:list to see which features is available out of the box.